# How to simlpify this Sum?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I want a simplified form of:

$$\displaystyle N = \sum_{\displaystyle 0 \leq 2m \leq n} \binom {n}{2m} 2^{n-2m}.$$

**Actual Question:**

There is $ 1 \times n$ rectangle which is broken into $n$ unit squares. Now each square is coloured with either Red, Green, or Blue colours (not necessary that every colour appear in the squares). Let $f(n)$ denote the number of colourings in which Red colour occurs even number of times $(0,2,4,...)$.

What will be the value of $\displaystyle \frac {f(9)}{f(3)} ?$

**My attempt:**

$\displaystyle f(9) = \binom {9}{0} \times 2^{9} + \binom {9}{2} \times 2^{7} + \binom {9}{4} \times 2^{5} + \binom {9}{6} \times 2^{3} + \binom {9}{8} \times 2^{1}$

Similarly $f(3)$.

Thus I added the terms indivisually... that took a lot of time, then I tried to simplify the summation, but I was unsuccesful in doing so...

I would pefer a hint, not the answer.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_m\binom{n}{2m}x^{2m}2^{n-2m}=\big(g(x)+g(-x)\big)/2$, where $g(x)=\ldots\binom{n}{m}\ldots$

Comment: @metamorphy Let me try it ... Thank you .

Comment: I did like this : $\displaystyle (x + 2)^n = \sum_{r=1}^n \binom {n}{r} x^r 2^{n-r}$ and $\displaystyle  (-x + 2)^n = \sum_{r=1}^n \binom {n}{r} (-x)^r 2^{n-r}$ for two cases when $n$ is odd and when $n$ is even. But even / odd case do not matter I think...

Comment: When you add them and replace $1$ for $x$ we get : $\displaystyle \frac {3^n + 1}{2}$

Comment: @metamorphy Thank you for the hint, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum is equal to:

$$S={3^n+1 \over 2}$$

Comment: I got the same answer....

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Use
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose 2k} x^{2k}=\frac{(1+x)^n+(1-x)^n}{2}$$
$$M=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose 2k} 2^{n-2k}=2^n \frac{(1+1/2)^n+(1-1/2)^n}{2}=\frac{3^n+1}{2}.$$
When $2k>n$, the vinomial coeffiocient vanishes.

Comment: Please explain how $k$ varies from $0$ to $n$, because $\binom {n}{2n}$  cannot be possible .... or am I wrong ?

Comment: @Nikola Alfredi  When $2k>n$ the binomial co-efficent vanishes. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Ok, I didn't knew that, cool...